# How to combine value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I want to combine value in one table

```
select sum(if(dep_id=2,point,0)) as totalpoint,
       sum(if(dep_id=3,point,0)) as totalpoint
from user_info
```

[image]

This is my table:

[image]

I want to result like this:

[image]

I dont know how to fix this. Please help me

Comment: You should have different column aliases.

Comment: Put your code into your question, rather than images. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select dep_id, sum(point) totalpoints
from user_info
where dep_id in (2, 3)
group by dep_id
```

If there are missing `dep_id`s in the table, and you still want them in the resultset, with a `0` value, then it is a bit different. An option is to enumerate the values in a derived table, then bring the original table with a join:

```
select d.dep_id, coalesce(sum(ui.point), 0) totalpoints
from (select 2 dep_id union all select 3) d
left join user_info ui on ui.dep_id = d.dep_id
group by d.dep_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UNION :

```
select dep_id, sum(point) as totalpoint
from user_info
where dept_id = 2
union 
select dep_id, sum(point) as totalpoint
from user_info
where dept_id = 3
```